# Please check my proof (arbitrary intersection of closed compact subset is compact)

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $\{C_j: j \in J\}$ be a family of cloesd compact subsets of a topological space $(X,\tau)$. Prove that $\bigcap_{j\in J}C_j$ is compact.

Let $C=\bigcup_{j\in J}C_j$ and let $\tau_1$ be a induced topology on $C$. Then $(C,\tau_1)$ must be a compact space. And $\bigcap_{j\in J}C_j$ is closed in $C$, hence it is compact.

I feel I am wrong as I should show $\bigcap_{j\in J}C_j$ is compact in $X$, not $C$. Also, I checked other answers with the same problem, someone says that the above statement only holds in hausdorff space. Does it mean that my textbook is wrong?

Comment: $C$ need not to be compact. For example, if $C_n =[-n,n] \subset \Bbb{R}$, then $\Bbb{R} = \bigcup_n C_n$ is not compact. Anyway, you don't need the union of the $C_j$. Note that $\bigcap_j C_j \subseteq C_{j_1}$, for a fixed $j_1 \in J$. SInce it is closed inside a compact set, it is compact.

Comment: @Crostul Thanks for counterexample !

Comment: @Crostul Can I say that $\bigcap_{j\in J}C_j \in C_k$ where $k$ is some element in $J$. Then Clearly, $C_k$ is compact space, and $\bigcap_{j\in J}C_j$ is closed in $C_k$. Hence, $\bigcap_{j\in J}C_j$ is compact?

Comment: Yes: this is exactly what I said above, and it is the correct way to solve the exercize. As you can see, it was easier than expected.